# Match keywords from a list and filter out the rest using regexp or other?

Tags: looker-studio

Ok so I'm familiar with the filter in Google Data Studio where strings can be filtered using AND or OR. The maximum however is 75 and I need 100. It's quite annoying though having to put one filter up at a time. Ideal would have been to be able to copy all keywords and paste them in.

Any solutions to this? Can this be done with for instance regexp?

Answer (score 0):

(?i)^(Keyword 1)$|^(Keyword 2)$|^(Keyword 3)$|^(Keyword 4)

So that is what I came up with above and it seems to work.

During copy from Google Sheets, is there a way to format a column of keywords into the regex format above?